# Фильтр пользователей в ActiveDirectory

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

Такой вопрос: нужно написать скрипт на PowerShell для вывода пользователей, что логинились с 8:00 до 18:00.

Для вывода пользователей написал данный код:

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)


Get-ADUser -Filter {((Enabled -eq $true) -and (LastLogonDate -lt $date))} -Properties LastLogonDate | where {$_.data –like “*12:00*”} | select samaccountname, Name, LastLogonDate | Sort-Object LastLogonDate | Export-csv -path c:lstlg.csv
```

Получается через where {$_.data –like “*12:00*”} вывод тех, кто логинится в 12:00. И каждый час с каждой минутой фильтровать неправильно, как мне кажется.
Как лучше написать фильтр?

Answer (score 0):

Можно задать конкретные дату и время, затем искать в промежутке между ними. Например:

```
$begin = Get-Date -Year 2022 -Month 09 -Day 06 -Hour 08 -Minute 00 -Second 0

# Мне нравится такой способ задания даты и времени, чтобы не ошибиться,
# особенно, если приходится использовать компьютеры с разными региональными настройками 
# вы можете использовать тот, который нравится вам

$end = Get-Date -Year 2022 -Month 09 -Day 06 -Hour 18 -Minute 00 -Second 0

# Затем, чтобы каждый раз не задавать конкретные значения, можете
# отнимать/прибавлять целое количество дней посредством AddDays, AddHours и т.д.
# например, можно было задать $end = $begin.AddHours(10)

Get-ADUser -Filter {((Enabled -eq $true) -and (LastLogonDate -ge $begin) - and (LastLogonDate -le $end))} <...>

# Ищем, кто логонился в промежутке между $end и $begin
```

В принципе, если вам подобный скрипт нужен часто, можно даже создать форму ввода для даты/времени, но это уже несколько иной уровень владения powershell :)